# For p, an odd prime, prove that $(p-3)! ≡ (p-1)*(2)^{-1}\pmod p$

Tags: number-theory

Here is what I got so far:

$$(p-3)! \equiv (p-1)(2)^{-1} \pmod p\\
(p-3)(p-2)(p-1)! \equiv (p-1)(2)^{-1}  \pmod p$$
Since $p$ is prime, by Wilson's theorem, $(p-1)! \equiv -1 \pmod p$. Hence,
$$\begin{align}(-1)(p-3)(p-2) &\equiv (p-1)(2)^{-1}\pmod p\\
-p^2 +5p -6 \equiv -6 &\equiv (p-1)(2)^{-1}\pmod p\\
-6(2) \equiv -12 &\equiv (p-1)\pmod p\\
-12 + 1 &\equiv p\pmod p\\
-11 &\equiv p\pmod p\end{align}$$

This is what I got so far. Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: I'm sorry for my lack of TeX. I don't know how to use it...

Comment: $(p-3)!\neq (p-1)!(p-2)(p-3)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** We have 
$p-1\equiv -1\equiv (p-1)!=(p-3)!(p-1)(p-2)\equiv (p-3)!(-1)(-2)\equiv 2(p-3)!\pmod{p}$.

**Remark:** Your proof begins in the right way, Wilson's Theorem is the correct tool.  After that there are problems. We are trying to get information about $(p-3)!$, but it does not appear explicitly in the rest of the calculation.

Comment: What did you use to get p−1≡−1?

Comment: @user80979: $0 < a < p \implies p-a \equiv -a$

Comment: Is that because p≡p mod(p) hence, we're just left with -1?

Comment: @user80979  More like $p \equiv 0 \mod p$. And yes. But alternatively, It's also common sense

Comment: In general, $p-k\equiv -k\pmod{p}$, since their difference is divisible by $p$. It is often useful to think of $p-1$ as "the same thing" (modulo $p$) as $-1$, and of $p-2$ as the same thing as $-2$. That is the key to proof.

Comment: Thanks guys! @André Nicolas, you've been of tremendous help! You must be a number theorist.

Comment: I am not. But have taught elementary number theory quite a few times.

Comment: $\pmod p$ isn't an operator, it's an equivalence class.  Within that equivalence class, $p + k = p$.  You have to be careful though, because in the expression $a^b \pmod p$, $a$ is from the equivalence class but $b$ is just a natural number.

Answer (score 2):

In going from

$$(p-3)!\equiv (p-1)(2)^{-1}\pmod p$$
to
$$(p-3)(p-2)(p-1)!\equiv (p-1)(2)^{-1}\pmod p$$
you seem to be assuming that $(p-3)!=(p-3)(p-2)(p-1)!$.  That's not correct.  It works the other way:  $(p-1)!=(p-1)(p-2)(p-3)!$.  Consequently all the rest of your derivation is invalid, which you should have realized when you got to $-11\equiv p\pmod p$, which basically says that $p$ can only be $11$.

It *is* appropriate to apply Wilson's theorem, but you need to do it along lines like this:

$$\begin{align}
p-1&\equiv-1\\
&\equiv(p-1)!\qquad\text{(by Wilson's Theorem)}\\
&=(p-1)(p-2)(p-3)!\\
&\equiv(-1)(-2)(p-3)!\\
&=2(p-3)!\\
\end{align}$$
and then bring the $2$ to the other side as $2^{-1}$.